# How can I retrieve comments from last 5 minutes for a post?

Tags: wp-query, comments

I need to find comments posted in last 5 minutes. I am using the following query. What should be the value of `before`?

```
        <?php 
        $postID = get_the_ID();
        wp_list_comments(array(
            'date_query' => array(
                'after' => '5 minute ago',
                'before' => ?,
                'inclusive' => true,
                ),
            'post_id' => $postID,
            'status' => approve,  
        ));
        ?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the function `wp_list_comments()` doesn't fetch the comments, only displays them in various ways depending on the input arguments.

You're actually using the `WP_Comment_Query`/`get_comments` input arguments into `wp_list_comments()`.

You could try this instead:

```
$postID = 12345; // Adjust this!

$comments = get_comments( 
    [
        'date_query' => [
            'after'     => '5 minutes ago',
            'inclusive' => true,
        ],
        'post_id' => $postID,
        'status'  => 'approve',  
    ] 
);

printf( 
    '<ol>%s<ol>', 
     wp_list_comments( $args = [ 'echo' => 0 ], $comments )
);
```

where you can play with the comment output through the `$args` input array.

Check the Codex [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments).

Note that we can skip the `before` attribute when we use `after` attribute.